# EasyNetQ / RabbitMQ consuming events in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq, cqrs, event-sourcing, easynetq

I have created Web API which allows messages to be sent to the Queue. My Web API is designed with CQRS and DDD in mind. I want my message consumer to always be waiting for any messages on the queue to receive. Currently the way its done, this will only read messages if I make a request to the API to hit the method.
Is there a way of either using console application or something that will always be running to consume messages at anytime given without having to make a request from the Web Api. So more of a automation task ? 
If so, how do I go about with it i.e. if its console app how would I keep it always running (IIS ?) and is there way to use Dependency Injection as I need to consume the message then send to my repository which lives on separate solution. ?
or a way to make EasyNetQ run at start up ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this situation in your case is to subscribe to bus events using [AMPQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html) through EasyNetQ library. The recommended way of hosting it is by writing a windows service using [topshelf library](http://topshelf-project.com/) and subscribe to bus events inside that service on start.

IIS processes and threads are not reliable for such tasks as they are designed to be recycled on a regular basis which may cause some instabilities and inconsistencies in your application.

> and is there way to use Dependency Injection as I need to consume the message then send to my repository which lives on separate solution.

It is better to create a separate question for this, as it is obviously off-topic. Also, it requires a further elaboration as it is not clear what specifically you are struggling with.